# Can I enter Norway before the date stated on visa?

Tags: visas, norway

I have the visa from 4 Feb till 4 march but i wish to go there on 1st Feb. Is it possible to enter Norway before the 4 February?

Comment: No. Why do you think so it is allowed ? Your visa starts from a specific date and that is the date you are allowed into Norway.

Answer (score 6):

Not on that visa, no, as it's outside its period of validity.

However, **if** you really, really want to go before February 4th, your only option at present would be to obtain a new visa that covers the period you actually want to travel.

Answer (score 5):

No you cannot. They won't even let you board on the plane to Norway (or any other destination where you need a valid visa) if it seems you won't be able to legally enter the country at the arrival time. Taking a flight the day before would in that sense be acceptable in case of an overnight journey, but that doesn't seem to be your case.